# Tex: "An error occurred submitting the question."

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, latex

I'm trying to paste the following question to no avail. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

> Some letters of the greek alphabet  include alternative letters. For
>   instance, we have `\Phi`, `\phi` and `\varphi`.
>
> What is the purpose of the variant versions of these letters? Why are
>   these not available for the entire greek alphabet?
>
> Information about these symbols:
>   https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Greek_letters
>
> The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List from CTAN does not mention their
>   purpose either.

Comment: Did this occur on the [Tex.SE] site? If so, why haven't you posted it on [their meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @CodyGray He doesn't have the necessary reputation there. You need 5 Rep to post on meta sites.

Comment: It did. It was a mistake. Is it possible to move it there or should I delete it here and repost on the correct place?

Comment: @RalZarek Right, I got: "You must have at least 5 reputation on TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange to ask a question.".

Comment: Must have been divine intervention. After a lot of tries the post was submitted on `TeX - LaTeX`. I did not change anything, just waited a couple of additional minutes.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Sorry, I didn't think to check your reputation on that site. A moderator can migrate this question to the TeX meta if they feel it is appropriate, but it's OK to ask it here, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be working again in rev 2013.8.23.966